# Texture is not Binding

Tags: java, opengl, textures, lwjgl

I've been having a problem with lwjgl and slick 2d where the texture won't bind. There aren't any compiation errors, it just outputs a white box where the texture is supposed to go.

Here is the code i used

```
public static void BeginSession() {
        try {
            Display.setTitle("Game Tower");
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH,HEIGHT));
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Boot.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0,WIDTH,HEIGHT,0,-1,-1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        
        
    }

public static void DrawQuadText(Texture tex,float x, float y, float width, float height) { 
        float ndcX1 = (2.0f * x) / Display.getWidth() - 1.0f;
        float ndcY1 = 1.0f - (2.0f * y) / Display.getHeight();
        float ndcX2 = (2.0f * (x+width)) / Display.getWidth() - 1.0f;
        float ndcY2 = 1.0f - (2.0f * (y+height)) / Display.getHeight();
          
        tex.bind();
        System.out.println(GL11.glGetError());  // this is where the error 1282 shows up
        glTranslatef(x,y,0);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f,0.0f);
        glVertex2f(ndcX1,ndcY1);
        
        glTexCoord2f(1,0);
        glVertex2f(ndcX2,ndcY1);
        
        glTexCoord2f(1,1);
        glVertex2f(ndcX2,ndcY2);
        
        glTexCoord2f(0,1);
        glVertex2f(ndcX1,ndcY2);
        
        glLoadIdentity();
        //System.out.println(GL11.glGetError());
        glEnd();
        
        
        
        }
        
        public static Texture LoadTexture(String path, String fileType) {
            // all of this seems to be working
            Texture tex = null;
            InputStream in = ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(path);
            try {
                tex = TextureLoader.getTexture(fileType,in);
                //System.out.println(GL11.glGetError());
                System.out.println(tex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Artist.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            System.out.println(path);
                return tex;
        }
```

This is the main function

```
public class Boot {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    
    public Boot() {

        BeginSession();
        
        int x1 = 100;
        int y1 = 100;
        int x2 = 200;
        int y2 = 200;
        
        Texture t = LoadTexture("towerdefenseproject/grass.png","PNG");
        System.out.println(GL11.glGetError());
        while(!Display.isCloseRequested())  {
            
            DrawQuadText(t,0,0,64,64);
            
            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);
        }
        
        Display.destroy();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        new Boot();
    }
    
}
```

Ihave tried everything i could think of too fix the issue but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

In Opengl immediate mode, two-dimensional texturing needs to be enabled, see [`glEnable`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnable.xml). Enable `GL_TEXTURE_2D`, before drawing the geometry with the `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequence:

```java
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```